# Customize UISegmentedControl like Tinder - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, tinder

How can I customize `UISegmentedControl`? Like this:

[image]

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3
I would appreciate it if you could help. Thanks.

Comment: See this [LUNSegmentedControl](https://github.com/LunApps/LUNSegmentedControl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get UISegmentControl like that from [LUNSegmentedControl](https://github.com/LunApps/LUNSegmentedControl)

It is in objctive C but you can convert it in swift and can use it in your project.